# Using Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core

Ive asked a variation on this question...so plz forgive me if this is a repetition.

I have some old bitcoin on a harddrive, Im not sure of the details, or amount.
I will be using Bitcoin Core as my wallet - Im in the process of installing and synching the wallet now.

The question :

Can I sync my wallet and THEN import my older wallet?
OR
Is there a different process altogether.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing you can use it. After the import you should sync the blockchain, then you can see all transaction associated with your adress. Be sure that Port `8333` is forwarded to your machine. If you want to import your old wallet you have 2 choices:

1. Import the Private Key
2. Import the wallet

**Import the private key**
Open bitcoin core and then open the console. In the console enter

```
importprivkey [your private key]
```

**Import the wallet**
Open the folder where Bitcoin Core is installed, then rename or delete `wallet.dat` and finally move your old `wallet.dat` into this directory.

You can also move your Bitcoins from your old wallet with Electrum which doesn't need to sync the blockchain

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure you can do that. Don't forget to rescan the blockchain after you import your wallet.

Comment: Thank you adam, will this require the lengthy syncing process when initially installing BITCOIN Core?

Comment: No, you only need a rescan. Not a full reindex (which is what happens at initial sync). Both are lengthy processes, but rescanning is usually an order of magnitude faster at least.